# How to Iterate Dataset<Row> and print each attribute value in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have loaded a parquet file into a `Dataset<Row>` in `java` and I want to iterate it record/row wise and read value of every attribute in that row.

I have got till here

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("parquet").load(location);
        df.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> {
            System.out.println(row);
        });
```

Is there any function for it in `java` to read attributes of a given row?

PS : I am using java 11 and spark 2.4.0.

Comment: There is some chance that the combination of Java 11 and Spark 2.4.x is not going to work very well with Java 11. You need Spark 3.0 or newer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its a little tricky for java, as java doesn't support searching a column directly by its name, but we can get a column based on index.
Also there is a function which returns the field-index of a given column name. Combining both we can iterate over the attributes of `DataSet<Row>`

Sample code:

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("parquet").load(location);
        df.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> {
            System.out.println((String) row.get(row.fieldIndex("attribute_name")));
        });
```